# Submit button not working Django and Bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-templates

I have made a small blog app using Django. Without applying Bootstrap, the app works fine. However, after adding Bootstrap, the submit button of the comment submission form does not work. Nothing happens on clicking it: no update on the terminal and no rerouting in the browser.

I have tried the following, but in vain:

- used `forms.py` and generated forms using Django
- used `django-bootstrap3` for applying bootstrap
- used HTML forms directly

App without Bootstrap (submit button works fine): https://github.com/amandal1810/blogspot

App with Bootstrap (submit button won't work): https://github.com/amandal1810/blogspot/tree/bootstrapped

There are two `post` template files in `templates` directory. The `post2.html` is uses a direct HTML form approach, whereas the `post.html` uses a `forms.py` Django form rendering approach.

I guess the error is somewhere in the template.

Comment: hey could you post the rendered HTML code in the bootstrap version

Comment: @awwester here's the rendered html of the form section in the bootstrap version.

http://pastebin.com/ueztbFN2
Thank you again.